How can you connect a computer to a Raspberry Pi 1B?
I have a Raspberry Pi 1B that I'm trying to convert to a security camera I can access from anywhere. I have tried connecting to it via VNC and SSH, but VNC requires Wi-Fi (which the Pi 1B doesn't have) and SSH requires you to be on the same network. Also, the Pi 1B can't run Chromium. Do you have any tips on how to complete this task?

Not a Pi problem. The same would apply to any computer.

You can use a compatible USB Wi-Fi adapter for your Raspberry Pi 1B.

I'm not fully understanding the issue. Is it the fact that we're trying to get the Pi to connect to the PC from far away? Or is it that we need to get it connected to set it up?

I'm trying to connect to the Pi from far away.

"SSH requires you to be on the same network" -> 100% FALSE.  This is true to the same extend as any other networking application.  If you can ping the Pi or connect to it in any way from where-ever, you can ssh from there as well.

You can connect your Pi to your router via an ethernet cable, and port forward the ports of the VNC or SSH service to your public IP. That way, wherever you are, just connect to your public IP and you should be in.

Note that most ISP's do not provide a stable public IP unless you pay extra for it, and it is not a nominal fee.  Your address will tend to be the same for a some period of time (likely days) but is eventually subject to arbitrary change.  Using an external VPN server or a DDNS service (some of which are very cheap or even free, I think) is the usual solution to that.

@goldilocks If that's the case, would it be better to use 3rd party remote tools?

Both of those arguably count as third party tools unless you already have your own server somewhere with a stable IP you could use as the VPN gateway (this is my preferred methodology).  I've never actually used a DDNS, but my impression is that they are not difficult.

I usually use ZeroTier for connecting remotely to my Pi. It builds a tunnel interface on your Pi. You can add other devices in same to VPN network (up to 25 devices for free subscription). I added my Pi and my phone and used to connect to my Pi while I am outside by connecting my phone to ZeroTier VPN and accessing my Pi via ZeroTier IP it has on its tunnel interface.
You can google and get all the info you want from their website.

Could you please clarify on how to install it?

This link shall be useful. You can google for youtube or maybe instructions in official website. I am, unfortunately, on confined network and I have many blocked websites so can't help by copying some resources.
https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-zerotier/
Hope this helps.
